# Decode byte message in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to decode this message below. For some reason I keep getting error. I tried everything on google but no success.

```py
b'6362561400022,B,,\x00\x04\x14\x01\x0bPQ=\n\x15(3\x19\x1a<\x1e\x80\x00\x00\xc8\x04\r\xc6\xb1"\xc4\xf2D\xff\xcb\x02\x0c\xfe\x02\x00\x00\x00\nR\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

UPDATE. Found the solution

```py
int("0x" + ''.join([hex(x)[2:] for x in byte_string]), base=16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
int("0x" + ''.join([hex(x)[2:] for x in byte_string]), base=16)
```